# Least Squares: Is there a way to improve the performance of this code? packages used: sm.OLS and pd

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, statsmodels, least-squares

Following function calculates the slope and intercept from a pandas data frame. For big data the calculations takes too long.

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm

df = pd.DataFrame({'signal': [270400, 270320, 270278.2609, 270195.8333, 270207.1429, 270081.8182, 269891.3043, 269991.6667, 270153.3333, 270285, 270357.1429, 270485.7143, 270526.3158, 270422.7273, 270310.7143, 270486.3636, 270593.9394, 270655.5556, 270669.2308, 270800, 270911.1111, 271083.3333, 271180, 271084.6154, 270800, 270966.6667, 271100, 271030.7692, 271053.8462, 271123.8095, 271050, 271165.5172, 271384, 271486.6667, 271554.5455, 271600, 271629.1667, 271526.6667, 271612.5, 271663.6364, 271553.5714, 271384, 271400, 271676.9231, 271666.6667, 271624, 271540.7407, 271503.125, 271600, 271620.8333, 271426.087, 271492.8571, 271482.1429, 271426.3158, 271207.6923, 271146.6667, 271057.8947, 271000, 271005.5556, 271044, 270930.4348, 270707.6923, 270833.3333, 270950, 270912.5, 270850, 270711.1111, 270925.9259, 271270, 271220, 271050, 271069.2308, 271037.5, 270954.5455, 270720, 270631.25, 270450, 270387.5, 270196, 270271.4286, 269920, 269760, 269562.5, 269500, 269867.8571, 269792.8571, 269854.1667, 269666.6667, 269417.3913, 269183.3333, 268966.6667, 268859.0909, 268707.6923, 268634.4828, 268516.6667, 268500, 268753.3333, 269175, 269309.5238, 269440.9091, 269394.4444, 269147.3684, 269133.3333, 269083.3333, 269126.087, 269145, 269164.7059, 269175, 269247.3684, 269540.9091, 270039.2857, 270150, 270283.3333, 270480.9524, 270692.8571, 270350, 270414.2857, 270277.7778, 270359.2593, 270148.1481, 269905, 269800, 269731.8182, 270186.6667, 270271.4286, 269983.3333, 269808, 269900, 269652.381, 269434.6154, 269659.2593, 269770.9677, 269831.0345, 269960, 270000, 270021.7391, 269868.4211, 269421.0526, 269106.25, 268813.3333, 268685.7143, 269421.4286, 269712.5, 269546.1538, 269332.2581, 269103.3333, 269289.2857, 269493.5484, 269650, 269710, 269444.4444, 269727.2727, 269833.3333, 269844.4444, 269985.7143, 270445.4545, 270320, 270092.5926, 269978.9474, 269866.6667, 269666.6667, 269468.75, 269582.3529, 269300, 269336.3636, 269309.5238, 269233.3333, 269208, 269100]  })

def OLS_slope_intercept(df,select_colname='open'):
    model = sm.OLS(df[select_colname], sm.add_constant(df.index)).fit()
    intercept = model.params[0]
    slope = model.params[1]
    return slope, intercept

import time
start = time.time()
slope, intercept = OLS_slope_intercept(df,'signal')
end= time.time()
print('running time of code:' +str(end-start))
```

Comment: Both answers improve the performance significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [**`scipy.stats.linregress`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) which is faster than `statsmodels`:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

def OLS_slope_intercept(df,select_colname='open'):
    model = sm.OLS(df[select_colname], sm.add_constant(df.index)).fit()
    intercept = model.params[0]
    slope = model.params[1]
    return slope, intercept

import time
for i in [10,100,1000,10000,100000]:
    df1 = pd.concat([df]*i)
    start = time.time()
    slope, intercept = OLS_slope_intercept(df1,'signal')
    end= time.time()
    print('running time of for STATSMODEL Library: ' +str(end-start))

    start = time.time()
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(df1.index,df1.signal)
    end= time.time()
    print('running time of for SCIPY Library code: ' +str(end-start))


    start = time.time()
    coeffs = np.polyfit(df1.index, df1.signal, 1) # 1=linear
    end= time.time()
    print('running time of for Numpy Library code: ' +str(end-start),'\n')
```

---

```
running time of for STATSMODEL Library: 0.018347978591918945
running time of for SCIPY Library code: 0.0010001659393310547
running time of for Numpy Library code: 0.0009999275207519531 

running time of for STATSMODEL Library: 0.005003690719604492
running time of for SCIPY Library code: 0.0010006427764892578
running time of for Numpy Library code: 0.0010006427764892578 

running time of for STATSMODEL Library: 0.033023834228515625
running time of for SCIPY Library code: 0.0010905265808105469
running time of for Numpy Library code: 0.0 

running time of for STATSMODEL Library: 0.2552676200866699
running time of for SCIPY Library code: 0.050981998443603516
running time of for Numpy Library code: 0.11161375045776367 

running time of for STATSMODEL Library: 2.6753437519073486
running time of for SCIPY Library code: 0.3832666873931885
running time of for Numpy Library code: 1.2618811130523682
```

Comment: My conclusion: On average np.polyfit is 5% faster than linregress from scipy.stats.

Comment: @mqx check the update `linegress` is faster than `np.ployfit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `numpy.polyfit()`

```
import numpy as np
import time

start = time.time()
coeffs = np.polyfit(df.index, df.signal, 1) # 1=linear
end= time.time()

slope, intercept = coeffs

print(f'Run Time: {end-start}\nSlope: {slope}\nIntercept: {intercept}')

Run Time: 0.000385284423828125
Slope: -10.83867485480565
Intercept: 271144.8357256735
```

When I run your example `running time of code:0.002992868423461914`